# Apache CXF with spring shows "unwinding now" exception

Tags: java, web-services, websphere, cxf

I am using Apache CXF with spring in a web application and its deployed on Websphere 6.1 and it works fine, While migrating to Websphere 7.0, we are getting some issues when calling the webservice part.

The Exception says

> org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doIntercept Application has thrown    exception, unwinding now: serverErrororg.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doIntercept Application has thrown    exception, unwinding now:[11/9/10 21:08:04:197 GMT+05:30]"

It will be great if you could help in fixing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to figure it out, it's due to the websphere's jaxws runtime, we removed following jars from the application library and set parent class loading last in server lever class loader, and it worked.

jars removed:
xml-schema
xml-api
webservices-api
stax-api
stax-util
jaxb-xjc - also remove if there are any jaxp related jars...

we also had problem with spring version and upgraded the jars related to spring..